# rewrite controller not working

Tags: magento-1.9, error, overrides, controllers

can you help me? i train make rewrite controller on magento 1.9.2.4 and i'm using php 7, my code like this
Lesson/Test/controllers/CartController.php

```
<?php
require_once "Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php";
class Lesson_Test_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    # Rewrite of indexAction
    public function indexAction() {
        die('your method has been rewrited !!');
    }
}
```

Lesson/Test/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <Lesson_Test>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Lesson_Test>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Lesson_Test before="Mage_Checkout">Lesson_Test</Lesson_Test>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

etc/modules/Lesson_All.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
        <modules>
            <Lesson_Test>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Lesson_Test>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

but it not work, 404 not found, i acces http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-tutorial/index.php/lesson
thank you magento :) i'm learn from this

Comment: What if you access  http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-tutorial/index.php/checkout/cart ? As it is an overriden controller you should access the native controller route and your overriden controller class would be used instead

Comment: thanks @RaphaelatDigitalPianism its solved my problem, i was wrong for my access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here.
But rewriting a controller, does not mean that you can change the url key for that controller.
Your custom code should be called when your url is `checkout/cart/index` or simply `checkout/cart`.
There is no route defined for `lesson` in your `config.xml`.
If you want that to work you need to add this inside the `routers` tag:

```
 <lesson>
    <use>standard</use>
    <args>
        <module>Lesson_Test</module>
        <frontName>lesson</frontName>
    </args>
 </lesson>
```

and your controller will also respond at the url `lesson/cart`.
If you are trying to change the url key for checkout from `checkout` to `lesson` you need to add this inside the `routes` node in `config.xml`

```
  <checkout>
     <args>
        <frontName>lesson</frontName>
     </args>
  </checkout>
```